# Some issues with GroupJoin two tables by LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I have some tables in Database that they will be joined into an `Log` table.

Here is one of tables, and after that, i showed `Log` table

***User** entity*:

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public User()
    {
        Beneficiaries = new HashSet<Beneficiary>();
        Applicants = new HashSet<Applicant>();
        UserItemCategories = new HashSet<UserItemCategory>();
        UserPropertyCategories = new HashSet<UserPropertyCategory>();
        Payments = new HashSet<Payment>();
    }

    [Required]
    public Role Role { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public double FixedSalary { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfPay { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Beneficiary> Beneficiaries { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserItemCategory> UserItemCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserPropertyCategory> UserPropertyCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

**BaseEntity** class:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

***Log** entity*:

```
public class Log : BaseEntity
{
    public TrackTypeEnum Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string EntityId { get; set; }
}
```

In `Log` table, i wanted to join `entityId` into `User` table's Id
i wrote a code to handle that:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> Filtered<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> entities, IQueryable<Log> logDbSet) where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    var entitiesWithAttachedLogs = entities
        .GroupJoin(logDbSet, entity => entity.Id, log => log.EntityId, (entity, logs) => new
        {
            Entity = entity,
            Logs = logs
        });

    var groupedEntities = entitiesWithAttachedLogs.GroupBy(key => key.Entity.Id, value => new
    {
        value.Entity,
        Logs = value.Logs.DefaultIfEmpty()
    });

    var shrinkGroup = groupedEntities.SelectMany(group => group, (group, item) => new
    {
        TrackedEntity = item
    });

    var condition = shrinkGroup.Where(x =>
        (x.TrackedEntity.Logs == null || !x.TrackedEntity.Logs.Any())
        || (x.TrackedEntity.Logs.Any() && x.TrackedEntity.Logs.OrderBy(c => c.DateTime).FirstOrDefault().Type != TrackTypeEnum.Delete));
    var catchEntity = condition.Select(x => x.TrackedEntity.Entity);

    return catchEntity;
}
```

**Some rows may have no any log status.**

I'm going to get "NotDeleted" users:

```
var models = _users.Filtered(_logs);
var foundUser = await (from user in models
                       where user.Id == currentUser.Id
                       where user.Username == currentUser.Username
                       where user.Mobile == currentUser.Mobile
                       where user.Role == currentUser.Role
                       where user.Password == currentUser.EncryptedPassword
                       where user.FirstName == currentUser.FirstName
                       where user.LastName == currentUser.LastName
                       where user.Phone == currentUser.Phone
                       select user).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
return foundUser != null;
```

But when i want to get users that they aren't deleted ( based on `Log`'s `Type` property ), it returns this error:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'DefaultIfEmptyAsyncIterator`1[RealEstate.Domain.Tables.Log]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[RealEstate.Domain.Tables.Log]'.
```

please help me to fix that, and get specific rows that they aren't deleted according to `Log` state.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently somewhere the type is not what you thought it would be. Did you use your debugger to check the return value of the `select`? is this the input you hoped for `FirstOrDefaultAsync`? And what did you expect as return value of `FirstOrDefaultAsync`? Did you try to type all types literally, instead of var, and did you try do do this in smaller steps to see where the type error started?

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse i already checked everything you said, but didn't work and i changed above codes basically in my project.

Comment: So, what is the return value of Select?